# Google Sign in API - get photo Uri is null

Tags: android, google-signin

I was using Google Sign in API to request user profile, likes user display name, avatar photo. I got **null** value GoogleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl(), got value GoogleSignInAccount.getDisplayName().

Gmail account ok, but private account is not. private account is linked to Google gmail, it can see the picture in my Gmail account and Google Play store app, Google plus too. but why I got null value with using Google Sign In account API.

```
   GoogleSignInOptions.Builder builder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail();

        builder.setAccountName(userAcc);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = builder.build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


 private void handleSignInResult(final GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
        if (getBaseContext() == null) {
            return;
        }
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        final String email = acct.getEmail();
        final String displayName = acct.getDisplayName();
        final Uri uri = acct.getPhotoUrl();

        String sUri = null;
        if (uri != null) {
            sUri = uri.toString();
        }

        System.out.println("GoogleSignInAccount: getPhotoUrl: " + sUri);
```

Comment: Please check if your Google account has had Google+ profile picture or not.

Comment: I have checked on Google+ profile, it has profile picture.

Comment: Now ok. I have to remove the account from my device and then add the account. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/USER_ID?fields=image&key=AIzaSyBz2jGjZl0VGkllxYYKRHPuuAX_oMxdyVQ` , return json containing avatar

Comment: Thanks!! I have fixed the issue by removes the account and then add the account on my device.

Comment: @Joyofio987 if my answer help u, up prove=)