# Gmail sign in integration into android application, profilePhoto always null?

Tags: android, google-plus, gmail-api

We have integrated Gmail sign in into our Android application, we are using server-side integration to get one time auth_code as mentioned here : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

We are getting Gmail account access at both server end as well as Android device within our application.

But somehow we are not getting profile photo, using below method :

```
googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl();
```

While makeing request we are using following code :

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY))
                        .requestServerAuthCode("OUR_SERVER_CLIET_ID", true)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestProfile()
                        .build();
```

Some of the questions on stackoverflow suggest if user has Google+ account enabled with profile photo then only you will get the photo url. This is not happening in our case as we tested with account which has photo on Google+ account.

Similar integration we have done in our iOS application in which we are able to get profile photo url ? What might be wrong ?

**Update :**

It appears only for users who has photo set on profile will get photo url otherwise null.

Comment: I had same issue [this worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36760516/6007359)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update :**

It appears only for users who has photo set on profile will get photo url otherwise null.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code snippet i am getting user's account id, email, displayname, photourl

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext).enableAutoManage((AppCompatActivity) activity, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent,1);
```

And in onActivityResult i m getting those values in acct

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage((AppCompatActivity) activity);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                Log.e("user_id",acct.getId());
                Log.e("user_id",acct.getEmail());
                Log.e("user_id",acct.getDisplayName());
                Log.e("image_url",String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl()));
        }
    }
```

Just modified googlesignin builder accordingly.

Comment: Hi thanks for suggestion, I commented my code replaced with your code, though I see no big difference in codes but result is still null for photo url.

Comment: 04-26 12:30:19.661 24357-24357/com.my.app E/user_id: <SOME_STRING_WITH_ALL_NUMBERS>
04-26 12:30:19.661 24357-24357/com.my.app E/user_id:<my_email>@gmail.com
04-26 12:30:19.661 24357-24357/com.my.app E/user_id: My Name
04-26 12:30:19.661 24357-24357/com.my.app E/image_url: null

Comment: I have renamed my package name, some fields with their description as it may contain private information can not share coz of security concerns

Comment: have you tried with other account as in im getting all the info

Comment: Yes I have tried account with Image on Google plus. On iOS we are getting image with initials even if user don't have image problem is only with Android

Comment: hey if possible can you provide me a dummy account so that i see in my module if i m getting image or not

Answer (score 0):

If any user doesnt set any profile pic then it will always be null. so you need to handle that scenario in your app.

```
if(acct.getPhotoUrl()!=null)
{
   personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
}
```

Comment: @Kushal Singla, Thanks for suggestion I have handled null condition already :)

Comment: @pcj may i eligible for bounty :P